# What is the type keyword in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Stumbled on the type keyword in Haskell:

```
type Item = String
```

but not sure what it does, how to use it or how it is different from `data`. The online google search has been of no help.

I tried implementing it in a code like this:

```
    import System.IO

main = do  
        putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
        type Item = String
        let test :: Item
        test = "chris"
        putStrLn test
```

but I got an error

> parse error on input ‘type’

Please in a lay man's term what is `type` and how can it be used and how is it different from data?

Comment: It is a type alias. It does not make sense to do this in an expression.

Comment: Simple aliases like this can be used to make code more readable, but no more type-safe. More productive uses provider shorter names for longer types, sometimes providing fixed values for type parameters. For example, `type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity` provides the `Reader` monad without having to make explicit use of the `ReaderT` monad transformer everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [*type alias*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type#Type_and_newtype). It means that you can use `Item` in your code where you can use `String` instead.

A type alias is often used when you for example want to give a name to more complex types. For example:

```
import Data.Map(Map)

type Dictionary = Map String String
```

here you thus can use `Dictionary` instead of each time writing `Map String String`.

It is furthermore often used if you want to specify that you are working with `Item`s, the alias is then used in the type signature and in the documentation, which is often better than writing `String`.

It is also used if you do not yet know what type you will use for a specific object. By using a type alias, you can the work with `Item`, and later if you change your made define a type for `Item` or make it an alias of another type. This makes it more convenient to change the types.

> I tried implementing it in a code like this:
>
> ```
> import System.IO
>
> main = do  
>     putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
>     type Item = String
>     let test :: Item
>     test = "chris"
>     putStrLn test
> ```

A type alias is defined at the top level, so not in a `do` block, that would make a type definition locally scoped. While, like [@moonGoose says](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/4020), there are some proposals to make type definitions more locally scoped, currently it is not the case.

You can define the type alias like:

```
import System.IO

type Item = String

main = do  
    putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
    let test :: Item
        test = "chris"
    putStrLn test
```

Comment: it doesnt work, I am met with the error `parse error on input ‘=’`

Comment: @Oto-ObongEshiett: that's because you made an indentation error :)

Comment: I'm not convinced by the final paragraph. I think local type aliases would be useful (especially in conjunction with scoped type variables), though I do primarily have a `where` clause in mind rather than `do` block. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/4020

Answer (score 2):

```
type A = B
```

means exactly the same as

```
typedef B A
```

in C or C++, and it behaves basically the same as simply

```
a = b
```

except that `A` and `B` are type-level entities, not value-level ones. For example

```
Prelude> type A = Int
Prelude> :i A
type A = Int    -- Defined at <interactive>:1:1

Prelude> a = 37
Prelude> a
37
```

Because now `A = Int`, I can then use the type identifier `A` exactly everywhere I could also use `Int` directly:

```
Prelude> 37 :: Int
37
Prelude> 37 :: A
37
```

and even

```
Prelude> (37 :: Int) :: A
37
```

Note that there is *no* type conversion going on here, like you might have in other languages. `Int` and `A` are simply different names for *the same* type, so annotating with both is merely a tautology.

Contrast this with `data` (or `newtype`), which define a *new, separate* type which just happens to contain the, well, *data* of the specified type.

```
Prelude> data A' = A' { getA :: Int }
Prelude> (37 :: Int) :: A'

<interactive>:12:2: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘A'’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: (37 :: Int) :: A'
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (37 :: Int) :: A'
```